# Usage of RtlComputeCrc32 to calculate a routine checksum

Tags: delphi

How i can use the RtlComputeCrc32 routine to calculate a checksum/size of a routine?
example i need calculate the checksum of the routine above:

```
procedure Teste2;
begin
  MessageBox(0, 'Test', 'Info', 0);
end;
```

at https://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/RtlComputeCrc32.html say

```
DWORD RtlComputeCrc32
 (
  DWORD       dwInitial,
  const BYTE* pData,
  INT         iLen
 )
```

at delphi it should be

`function RtlComputeCrc32(dwInitial : DWORD; const pData: TByteArrs; iLen: Integer): DWORD; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';`

where TByteArrs is

```
type
  TByteArrs = array of Byte;
```

I ask that to prevent external people manipulate the memory, so prevent they hack it adding nops, jmp, or simply modifying the memory of program.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is this an undocumented function? If so, you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: Your checksum-protection can be easily hacked too.

Comment: And even if you managed to use this internal, undocumented Wndows function, how will you find the size of the routine?

Comment: As mentioned before, if someone has to knowledge to manipulate your program's code at runtime, they can also easily get rid of your CRC protection. Anyway, the following source code to a run-time debugger written in Delphi might help you: [Bug Finder](https://github.com/antonio-petricca/bug-finder).

Comment: NEVER use a ntdll.dll function in any of your project. Especially the undocumented functions! The one included in zlib will also be faster. You have plenty of hashers written in a few lines of native Delphi. Inlining those Delphi lines may be also slightly safer than calling a shared function.

Comment: i need know how use RtlComputeCrc32 from ntdll.dll

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample Delphi code for RtlComputeCrc32 usage. It calculates CRC-32 of a file and displays on windows console.

`program CRC32Calculation;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
    SysUtils, Windows;

function RtlComputeCrc32(dwInitial: DWORD; const pData: PByte; iLen: Integer): DWORD; stdcall;
    external 'ntdll.dll' name 'RtlComputeCrc32';

const
    InputFile = 'somefile.bin'; // Set the input file name here

var
    FileBytes: TBytes;
    Crc32: DWORD;
    Crc32String: string;
begin
   // Read the file as bytes
   FileBytes := TFile.ReadAllBytes(InputFile);

   // Calculate the CRC32 checksum using the Win32 API
   Crc32 := RtlComputeCrc32(0, @FileBytes[0], Length(FileBytes));

   // Convert the CRC32 value to hexadecimal string
   Crc32String := IntToHex(Crc32, 8);

   // Display the CRC32 checksum
   WriteLn('CRC32: 0x', Crc32String);   
end.`